# Identify an Armstrong number

Tags: c

I Wrote this code which can identify whether a number is a Armstrong number or not

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
     int n;
    const int input()
    {
        printf("insert n:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        return n;
    }   
    int Num_amount()
    {
      int amount=0;
      while(n>=10)
      {
          amount++;
          n=n/10;
          if(n<10)
            amount++;
      }
      return amount;
    }
    int Armstrong()
    {
        n=input();
        int v;
        int z=0;
        int y=10
      int x=Num_amount();
      int m[100]={};
      int i;
      for(i=0;n>=10;i++)
      {
          v=n%10;
        m[i]=pow(v,x);
        z=z+m[i];
        y=y*10;
      }
      return z;
    }
    int main()
    {
    int z=Armstrong();
    printf("%d",z);
    }
```

When run with **n=153** i always get **0**.After several debugging,I found out the problem is somewhere in the **Armstrong** function(most likely)

```
 int Armstrong()
            {
                n=input();
                int v;
                int z=0;
                int y=10
              int x=Num_amount();
              int m[100]={};
              int i;
              for(i=0;n>=10;i++)
              {
                  v=n%10;
                m[i]=pow(v,x);
                z=z+m[i];
                y=y*10;
              }
              return z;
        }
```

The debug watches indicate that instead of execute the **for** loop,it went straight to the **return z** line,I have tried everything but still can't figure it out.Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Use Num_amount(n) as n is a global variable

Comment: Change for loop from n >= to i<=

Comment: To start with 1. `for(i=0;n>=10;i++)` is infinite ie:  `n` is not getting changed inside the for loop hence remains the same . 2. what is the point of `n=input();` since `input` function is reading in `n` anyway?

Comment: constness of return value makes zero sense (`const int input()`)

Comment: Actually you will get errors as most of the code is wrong .Better you check again and again.That's the way you can become a good coder :)https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the wrong result because of some logical error. When you are choosing a variable to be `global`, you need to consider that the variable value can be modified by any `function` and in this case, you have already modified its value in `num_amount` function. You have also made some logical error in `Num_amount` and `Armstrong` function.
You haven't included `math.h` header file for `pow`.

Here is your modified code,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>    //<-------------Should have included 

         int n;
    const int input()
    {
        printf("insert n:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        return n;
    }  

    int Num_amount()       //<------------modified 
    {
        int z = n;        //<--------take a copy of global n
      int amount=0;
      while(z>0)
      {
          amount++;
          z=z/10;
      }
      return amount;
    }
    int Armstrong()         //<------------modified 
    {
        n=input();
        int v;
        int z=0;
      int x=Num_amount();
      int i;
      while(n>0)
      {
          v=n%10;
          z+=pow(v,x);
          n/=10;         //<-------modification of global n
      }
      return z;
    }


    int main()
    {
    int z=Armstrong();
    printf("%d",z);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm getting another problem is that instead of printing out 153 I got 152.As usual I started debugging to see the issue and I saw that  the Armstrong function worked just fine as first but when it divided by 10 the second time z's value became 151 instead of 152.It go like this:153%10=3 therefore z=27 and then 15%10=5 so z=27+125 but in this case it 27+124.Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Unknown I have checked the above-modified code. Have you tried the same code?

Comment: That's weird,I copied the code and tried to run it and it the same 152,maybe because of other problem in my computer,thanks for the help,i appreciate it

Comment: @Unknown for input `152` you should get `134` and for `153` the answer is `153`

Answer (score 1):

Found a lot problems with the code. Here is a modified version.
1. Do not use a global variable.
2. Make calculation for power easier.
3. Return the status of result, not the result. You want to check whether number is Armstrong or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int no_digits(int n){
  int digits = 0;
  while(n){
     digits++;
     n = n/10;
 }
  return digits;
}

int armstrong(){
  int n;
  printf("insert n:");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  int digits = no_digits(n);
  int curnum = 0,original = n;
  while(n){
    curnum += pow(n%10,digits);
    n /= 10;
  }

  if(original == curnum)
   return 1;
  return 0;
}
int main(){
  if(armstrong())
   printf("Is Armstrong\n");
  else printf("Not Armstrong\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your loop:

```
for(i=0;n>=10;i++)
{
  v=n%10;
  m[i]=pow(v,x);
  z=z+m[i];
  y=y*10;
}
```

What's the value of `n` at this point?  You've set it in the previous call to `Num_amount` like so:

```
while(n>=10)
{
  amount++;
  n=n/10;
  if(n<10)
    amount++;
}
```

So, after `Num_amount` has finished executing, `n` *must* be less than 10, meaning the loop in `Armstrong` won't execute.

This is a big reason why you shouldn't use globals, even in a toy program like this.  If you use it for different purposes in different places, you just create headaches like this.

At the very least, you should change your code such that `n` is passed as a parameter to `Num_amount` and `Armstrong`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function Num_amount() return "n" value is already less than 10 and for loop never run.